# Is it good practice to prevent of execution shell script?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I am using this htaccess code to prevent execution of shell script on my hosts upload directory:

```
<Files *.php.*>
Deny from All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Now I call the file named `shell.php.jpg` that has some php code in my upload directory and get `Error 403 : Access forbidden!` . This is what I want, But I want to ensure this is a correct way.

Is it good practice?

Comment: Why you need to do that??
if the mime type of the file is `JPG` it will not be passed to the PHP engine anyways!!

Comment: echo mime_content_type('shell.php.jpg'); // prints image/jpeg

Comment: What i'm trying to say that there is no threat of uploading php code in a jpg file, since it will not be treated as php file by your server and that is standard (you don't need to do anything further)!

Comment: Could you provide more information on who is uploading content, who is downloading content afterwards and how much traffic you are expecting? Additionally it would be helpful to know information like do you need a permission management or anything to give a good advice on what to do.